# Writing data with python script and cron

Tags: python, cron

I have already seen a lot of questions around this.. and a lot of proposed solutions. But none have worked for me so far. So here we go...

A simple python script called `test.py`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3


from datetime import datetime
print('Im alive')
fn = 'msgs.txt'                                                                 
with open('/home/username/Documents/code/production/msgs.txt', 'aw') as f:
    f.write('%s\n' % datetime.now())
```

And here the line in the `sudo crontab -e` file

```
*/1 * * * * /home/username/Documents/code/production/test.py >> /home/username/outputlog.txt
```

The log shows that the program runs and executes properly, I have used full paths in specifying the file that Im writing too, stated the job in `sudo crontab` in case anything goes wrong with the user... and at this point I am lost. I don't know what to change anymore and all others questions that Ihave seen wont help me further.

Anyone else has another idea here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short Answer: Change 'aw' file open mode to 'a'

With your current code, you'll get the error

> ValueError: must have exactly one of create/read/write/append mode

because you are trying to combine append ('a') and write ('w') modes. Simply using append ('a') mode fixes the problem.

Comment: Ah yes, thanks. While I was writing the question I was double checking everything, and there was one thing I forgot.

I did test the python script using python test.py, which worked.. but then I noticed that I should use python3 test.py. This indeed gave this error, after that it all worked like a charm. Thanks!